# View not displaying updated xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

For some reason when i update my xib and save my view loads an older version of the xib...I copied this project folder from a previous version..anyone ran into this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all check that you have saved your xib changes.
1. remove your application from simulator or device
2. Delete build folder of your app.(you can see path in xcode,prefrances, building prefrances)
3. Clean All form xcode->product-> Clean. Then run your  project.

Try this.It will work

Comment: Ah, yeah!  Now I remember that I had to shut down the emulator before building (and then modify the XIB one more time) for some reason.  I think the emulator had a lock on something.

Comment: Actually, doing Clean product is enough

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this problem.  It seems like the system wasn't detecting that the XIB had been changed for some reason, and was using the old internal copy of it in the build.  IIRC, changing the XIB eventually cleared up the problem, but I had to try several times.

Isn't Xcode wonderful??

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen on one of my apps. Somehow I'd accidentally unticked my Target on the .xib file in question, so it wasn't being bundled with the app anymore. Make sure your .xib is a member of your application target, and is listed in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase.

Comment: I also looked the xib that's being compiled to my target, the problematic xib is missing. This solved for me. The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I would guess that for some reason the new project is storing the paths from the older project you copied from. Perhaps the .xib being loaded in the editor is the one from your older project directory, and the program is loading the .xib from the new directory, or vice versa. Or, on the other hand, maybe its storing a cached version of the .xib that's already in the build? Perhaps doing a clean rebuild by removing all compiled output would remedy the issue?

Comment: clean rebuild doesn't work. what's weird is that i did a reset in ios sim and now it isn't linking to the xib

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once. I realized I had changed the storyboard name, but didn't change it in the project's summary page, in the section "iPhone/iPod Deplyment Info". Make sure you have the proper name of your storyboard selected there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Product from menu bar and select Clean and run the application again..Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Close the emulator before saving the changes to the .xib.